# Return a value to main function with pointers

Tags: c, function

Is there any other way to return a value to `main` function using `void` functions. I don't want to use the following way because I want to ask user to enters some values in main function and then check if those values are correct in the `void` function.

```
#include <stdio.h>
void fun_1(int *num1, int *num2) {

        printf("Enter both numbers: ");
        scanf("%d", num1);
        scanf("%d", num2);
}

int main(void) {

        int num1, num2, total;

        fun_1(&num1, &num2);

        total = num1 + num2;

        printf("%d \n", total);
}
```

In this code we ask user to enter values in `void` function, but I would like to ask user to enter values in `main`!

Comment: in that case, why do you have the other function?

Comment: @SouravGhosh I just want to learn if there is another way if possible!

Comment: If you want to have the user input the numbers in the `main` function then why do you have `fun_1` in the first place?

Comment: The whole point of functions returning `void` is that _they return no value_. They just, well, do stuff. If you want to get _information_ out of the function, return something, like `int`.

Answer (score 3):

There is another way to make use of global variables, but as your program grows more complex, it will probably create more hassles for you then it is worth.

If you use global variables to store your inputs inside the sub-function, then you can directly access them in your `main()` function to get the values. You won't be needing a `return` from your sub-function.

Having said that, it would be better to change the function return type (maybe returning a `struct` containing the user-supplied values, if you more than one value to be returned) to match your requirements.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to read the values in `main` but check them (ex. make sure both are positive) in another function, you can do this:

```
#include <stdio.h>

void check_numbers(int num1, int num2, int *valid) {
    if ((num1 > 0) && (num2 > 0)) {
        *valid = 1;
    } else {
        *valid = 0;
    }
}

int main(void) {
    int num1, num2, total, valid;

    printf("Enter both numbers: ");
    scanf("%d", num1);
    scanf("%d", num2);

    check_numbers(num1, num2, &valid);
    if (valid) {
        total = num1 + num2;
        printf("%d \n", total);
    } else {
        printf("numbers are invalid\n);
    }
}
```